# Extract list of specific frames to numpy array with ffmpeg

Tags: python, numpy, video, ffmpeg

To extract a list of specific frames to file I can use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='eq(n\,100)+eq(n\,184)+eq(n\,213)' -vsync 0 frames%d.jpg
```

And to extract frames sequentially to numpy:

```
command = [ 'ffmpeg',
            '-i', 'input.mp4',
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']

pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(420*360*3) 

image =  numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8') 

image = image.reshape((360,420,3))
```

Is it possible to combine these commands so that when I call `pipe.stdout.read(420*360*3)` the first time I get frame 100 and the second time frame 184 etc.

I have tried:

```
command = ['ffmpeg', 
           '-i', 'input.mp4', 
           'select=eq(n\,100)+eq(n\,184)+eq(n\,213)', 
           '-vsync', '0', '-f', 
           'image2pipe', '-pix_fmt', 
           'rgb24', '-vcodec', 
           'rawvideo', '-']
```

But I get the error:

```
[NULL @ 0x55718f7f6fc0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'select=eq(n\,20)+eq(n\,100)+eq(n\,500)'
select=eq(n\,20)+eq(n\,100)+eq(n\,500): Invalid argument
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is there no `-vf` option in the last command?

Comment: Thanks, that's done the trick - I needed an extra `-vf` to make the command: `command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp4', '-vf', 'select=eq(n\,100)+eq(n\,184)+eq(n\,213)', '-vsync', '0', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']`